# Не могу понять, где разница в двух кодах

Tags: c++

ВОт у меня есть два кода, они выполняют одно и то же. Но первый работает должным образом, а второй нет. Не могу понять, почему это так.В чем разница в последних двух строчках? Чем отличается

```
   (*p)->next = nexts.back();
    p = &(nexts.back()->next = tmp);
    nexts.pop_back();
```

от этого

```
    (*p)->next = nexts.back();
    nexts.back()->next = tmp;
    p = &nexts.back();
    nexts.pop_back();
```

Здесь самы коды в полной мере:

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode *next;
 *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution1 {
public:
    void reorderList(ListNode* head) {
        ListNode* current = head;
        vector<ListNode*> nexts;

        while(current != NULL){
            nexts.push_back(current);
            current = current->next;
        }
        if(nexts.size() < 2)
            return;
        auto** p = &head;
        while(true){
            auto* tmp = (*p)->next;
            if(tmp == nexts.back() || *p == nexts.back()){
                nexts.back()->next = NULL;
                break;
            }
            (*p)->next = nexts.back();
            p = &(nexts.back()->next = tmp);
            nexts.pop_back();
        }
    }
};

class Solution2 {
public:
    void reorderList(ListNode* head) {
        ListNode* current = head;
        vector<ListNode*> nexts;

        while(current != NULL){
            nexts.push_back(current);
            current = current->next;
        }
        if(nexts.size() < 2)
            return;
        auto** p = &head;
        while(true){
            auto* tmp = (*p)->next;
            if(tmp == nexts.back() || *p == nexts.back()){
                nexts.back()->next = NULL;
                break;
            }
            (*p)->next = nexts.back();
            nexts.back()->next = tmp;
            p = &nexts.back();
            nexts.pop_back();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Я не спец в Си, но кажется во втором случае нужно писать `p = &tmp;` что бы получилось одинаково

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первом случае после выполнения кода `p` указывает на `nexts.back()->next`, а во втором - на `nexts.back()`. Это совершенно разные места в памяти. Вот и вся разница.

Comment: Поняла, спасибо , извините за тупой вопрос)